# How to specify arrival date and time in Google Maps URL?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I tried using the `&ttype=arr&date=11/30&time=12:00`
Like I have found online, but this doesn't work unfortunately.

> comgooglemaps://?daddr=DESTINATION&saddr=FROMADDRESS&directionsmode=transit&ttype=arr&time=12%3A00&date=11%2F30

Opening the link with an iPhone opens the app.
Unfortunately, it doesn't change the date & time of the itinerary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the approach shown in this question still valid? When I look at the developer guide for basic Maps URLs, they make no mention of specifying and arrival time, and when I tack on the arrival time as shown in this question, from `&ttype` onward, it does not have any effect on the resulting directions. The dev guide I'm looking at is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to set the arrival time in URL params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrival date/time feature seems to only be available for public transit (which is your case) but [not on the mobile app](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleMaps/comments/3mid9z/did_google_maps_remove_departurearrival_time/), only on the web/desktop version of google maps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll link to the web version instead then! :) Maybe that'll start the app automatically with the right time? It's worth a try. Otherwise just use the web version.