# Google Maps Transit Directions URL with Arrival Time without using API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

I'm building a Google MAPs URL to launch in a new tab, and I'd like to specify Arrival Time for Transit directions. I am *not* using the API, just the basic URL options outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide).

It makes no mention of being able to specify arrival time. Some older posts do mention this for platform-specific cases, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977861/how-to-specify-arrival-date-and-time-in-google-maps-url) for iOS,  but they are using a very different looking URL format to what is outlined in the link above.

I know specifying Arrival Time requires you specify mode as transit, which I'm doing.

As an example, the following URL will bring up transit directions from 30 Rock in New York to the Metropolitan Museum of Art:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=30+Rockefeller+Plaza%2C+New+York%2C+NY+10112%2C+USA&destination=1000+5th+Ave%2C+New+York%2C+NY+10028%2C+USA&travelmode=transit

Without using the actual Google Maps API and all that entails (API Key, proxy server for security, paying per use), is there a modification to that URL that would allow me to specify an arrival date and time? I tried appending `&ttype=arr&date=05/13&time=08:00` as shown in the previous post I linked, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to file for a Feature Request regarding this in our Google Issue Tracker [1].

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects. You can learn more here [2].

[1] - https://issuetracker.google.com

[2] - https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/

Comment: I've found a request here, don't hesitate to start, it's a much needed feature ! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160453518